# Android AsyncTask class Hanged my Application why?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, loading, contacts

i call MyTask().execute(); in onCreate() of MainAcivity Class in my application. it Busy or Hang my application for long time. please help me why? i want my work in background so that it can't disturb my app. Why my app become busy and unresponsive?
Class code is below:

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    // Runs in UI before background thread is called
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        // Do something like display a progress bar
    }

    // This is run in a background thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        checkUser();

        return "";
    }

    // This is called from background thread but runs in UI
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        // Do things like update the progress bar
    }

    // This runs in UI when background thread finishes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Do things like hide the progress bar or change a TextView
    }
}
```

checkUser() method code is below

```
 private void checkUser(){

    // now here we convert this list array into json string


    final String server_url="http://www.xxxx.com/TruCaller/check_user.php"; // url of server check this 100 times it must be working



    // volley

    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {

                    final String result=response.toString().trim();
                    if(result.equals("not found")){
                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wait...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     //   Log.d("responsedd", "result not found fffffffff: "+result);
                        getContacts2();
                    }else{

                    }
                   // Log.d("responsedd", "result : "+result); //when response come i will log it
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    error.getMessage(); // when error come i will log it
                }
            }
    )
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("identifier", UIDD);

            Log.d("responsedd", "result not found ggggggggggg: "+ UIDD);
            return params;
        }
    };
    Vconnection.getnInstance(this).addRequestQue(stringRequest); // vConnection i claas which used to connect volley


}
```

getContacts2() method code is below:

```
  public void getContacts2() {

    if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
        return;
    }

   // contactList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String phoneNumber = null;
    String email = null;

    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

    Uri EmailCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

    StringBuffer output;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    // Iterate every contact in the phone
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        counter = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            output = new StringBuffer();


            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneC = "", adressC = "", emailC = "",country_code="";
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            String image = "";
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {




                ////////////////////Phone numbers with this name..... 2 Testing ....////////////////
                String phoneNumber2 = "";
                final String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,};
                final Cursor phone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact_id)}, null);

                if (phone.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int contactNumberColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);
                    phoneC = "";
                    while (!phone.isAfterLast()) {
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////

                        String x = phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex);
                        bitmap = retrieveContactPhoto(MainActivity.this, x);
                        String countryCode = countryCode(phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex));
                        country_code = countryCode;
                        // String swissNumberStr = "03348633664";
                        PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
                        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber pNumberProto;
                        String phoneVerfid="";
                        try {
                            pNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex), countryCode);
                         //   System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown:>>>>>>>>>>>> " + pNumberProto);
                            boolean isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(pNumberProto);
                            if(isValid){
                                System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(pNumberProto, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));
                                phoneVerfid = phoneUtil.format(pNumberProto, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
                            }
                        } catch (NumberParseException e) {
                           // System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString() +"   ???" +phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex) + countryCode);
                        }
                        ///////////////////////////////
                        phoneNumber2 = phoneVerfid + "_";
                        //   output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber2);
                        phoneC = phoneC  + phoneNumber2;
                        //  System.out.println("Country = "+countryCode(phoneNumber2) + "  p= " +phoneNumber2);
                        phone.moveToNext();

                    }

                }
                phone.close();


                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // Read every email id associated with the contact
                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI, null, EmailCONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);
                emailC = "";
                email = "";
                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA)) + "%";
                    if (!emailC.contains(email)) {
                        emailC = emailC  + email;
                        //  output.append("\n Email:" + email);
                    }
                }

                emailCursor.close();


                //////////// Adresss//////

                String postalData = "";
                String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{String.valueOf(contact_id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

                Cursor addrCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null);

                if (addrCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    postalData = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
                    //output.append("\n Address:" + postalData);
                    adressC = adressC + " " + postalData;
                }
                addrCur.close();


            }
            if (phoneC != "") {

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap1 = getResizedBitmap(bitmap,210);
                    image = getStringImage(bitmap1);
                    if(bitmap1!=null) {
                        bitmap1.recycle();
                    }
                   // System.out.println("KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK >>>>>>>>> "+image);
                }

                Contact_Details dt = new Contact_Details(name, phoneC, UIDD, country_code, image, emailC, adressC);
                dataArray.add(dt);
                if(bitmap!=null){ bitmap.recycle();}

                image = "";
            }

        }



                submit1User2Contacs();



    }

}
```

MainAcivity onCreate Method :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    new MyTask().execute();}
```

Comment: In the mountain of code you posted, you aren't actually calling MyTask.execute anywhere.

Comment: i call it in my main acivity. i Just not post here because of no need

Comment: @IbadUrRahman Yes it is... Please post that code.

Comment: i post it. please check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try below code instead of  new MyTask().execute() class. and the below code work for me. i also try below code with xxx.run(); method instead of start();. run() method also not work. only thread with xxx.start(); worked. so the correct code is below one. Thanks every one.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //my method
                                checkUser();
                            }
                        }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't called close method for cursor object.
Calling cursor.close() will solve your problem

Comment: what I could see in your is you've not closed the outer most Cursor. I don't see any other other for your application getting hanged.